# Disable Nginx Logging for "forbidden by rule"

Tags: nginx, logging

In my Nginx config I have some IP blocks in place, to fight off spammers & bots.

This is very effective, but as a result, my error logs get filled up super fast with error messages like these:

> 2015/12/16 00:56:28 [error] 27748#0: *120462 access forbidden by rule,
>   client: 167.114.xxx.xxx, server: bla bla ....

Now I don't want to fully disable error logging, as I want to find out what is going wrong when something goes wrong. I just want to disable logging of these "forbidden by rule" messages.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did you implement this in the end? If so, could you share your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/), use conditional logging ([`access_log` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)):

Enabling Conditional Logging

> Conditional logging allows excluding trivial or non-important log
> entries from the access log. In NGINX, conditional logging is enabled
> by the if parameter of the access_log directive.
>
> For example, it makes possible to exclude requests with HTTP status
> codes 2XX (Success) and 3XX (Redirection):
>
> ```
> map $status $loggable {
>     ~^[23]  0;
>     default 1; }
>
> access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
> ```

**EDIT:**
as @zsero described in comment, conditional logging is only supported with the `access_log` - not with the [`error_log` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log).

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not correct, the `if=` directive is not supported on error_logs, only access_logs. It terminates with `invalid log level "if=$loggable"`

Comment: So this won't help regarding the specific question, right?

Answer (score 2):

There is [better solution](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2149), suggested by upstream - to use geo block with if to reject requests like:

```
geo $blocked {
    default 0;
    1.1.1.1/32 1;
}
...
server {

  if ($blocked) {
    return 444;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this nginx config to ignore malicious requests on hidden files:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    return 444;
}
```

Returning a 444 ([Connection Closed Without Response](https://httpstatuses.com/444)) closes the connection and doesn't log any error.

Comment: i prefer using 418 im a teapot ;) but 444 might be a good idea